# how to execute remote operation to windows machine via nodejs

Tags: node.js, wmi

I finally joined the community

So for my first question in this community:

Generally I want to execute some remote operations to a remote windows machine in node.js (of course I  have permissions, credential and so on to the remote machine).

Specifically, right now I'm trying to retrieve list of services from windows machine.
I've tried using the wmi-client package in order to do so:

```
const WmiClient = require('wmi-client');
var wmi = new WmiClient({
    username: '*****',          //credentials - username 
    password: '*****',          //credentials - password
    host: '*********',          // remote windows machine
});

wmi.query(`Select * from Win32_Service`, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

but I keep receiving error: Exit code: 44125. Invalid Global Switch.

I'll mention that using wmi in powershell make no issues for me.
but when I trying to use the same technology in nodejs its failed.
what am I doing wrong? Any other suggestions?

just to mention, when I need to retrieve same info from linux machine I easiliy do it using 'simple-ssh' package, without any issues:

```
    const SSH = require('simple-ssh');
    
    var ssh = new SSH({
      host: '*******',         // remote linux machine
      user: '*******',         // credentials - username
      pass: '*******'          // credentials - password
    });

      ssh.exec(`systemctl list-units --full -all`, {
          out: function(stdout) {
            // stdout as expected
          }
      }).start()});
```

but things getting complicated when trying to do the same for windows remote machine.

any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the following is working for me:

```
var exec = require('node-ssh-exec');

var config = {
    host: '*******',
    username: '***',
    password: '***'
},
command = 'sc query';

exec(config, command, function (error, response) {
if (error) {
    throw error;
}
```

the response is as expected, but for some reason the error associated with it is not empty:

{
errno: -4077,
code: "ECONNRESET",
syscall: "read",
level: "connection-socket",
}